# Sending Push Notification via PHP Script

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have correctly setup my provisioning profile and application to receive **push notifications**, but I am struggling with using `PHP to send the notification`. I am using the script as outlined below, but am receiving this warning:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused).
```

I have done a bunch of research on this problem but am not sure how to resolve this issue. Any Ideas would be very helpful. THank you all!

```
<?php

$message=$_POST['message'];

if ($message)
{

    $device_token = "TOKEN_HERE";

    $payload = '{
    "aps": {
         "badge": 1,
         "alert": "Hello world!",
         "sound": "bingbong.aiff"
    }
}';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option ($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PEM_FILE_HERE' );
stream_context_set_option ($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'PASSPHRASE_HERE' );
$fp = stream_socket_client ('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 
60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
print "Failed";
return;
}
else {
print "Sent";
}

$devArray = array();
$devArray[] = $deviceToken;

foreach($devArray as $deviceToken) {
$msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack ('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack 
("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload . "n";
print "Sending Message :" . $payload . "n";
fwrite($fp,$msg);
}
fclose($fp);

}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type = "text" name = "message">
<input type = "submit" value = "Send Notification">
</form>
```

Comment: It may be your network connection issue ! Try creating socket for any other service and test weather socket creation is allowed or not ?

Comment: ensure pem file name and passphrase name are correct

Comment: sounds like a firewall problem.

Comment: @DevZer0 I think you are correct. I did some digging around and it appears that my shared GoDaddy hosting does not open port 2195. Hmmmmm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working script

```
 class Send_Push_Apple
 {
     public $apnsCert = 'PushProductionCertificatesWithKey.pem';


 function __construct()
  {
 /*
  * Nothing to fo Here
  *   
  * */ 

  }
static function send_push($data=array())
  {

    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => array('body' => $data['message'])); 
    $payload['aps']['badge'] = 1; 
    $payload['aps']['sound'] = 'default'; 
    $payload = json_encode($payload); 
    //For  development 
    //$deviceToken = '4e6ec248724ef635e#############################';  
    $deviceToken = $data['device_token'];

    //$apnsCert = 'DistPEMCertificate-05-05.pem'; 
    $streamContext = stream_context_create(); 
    //stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert',$apnsCert); 
    $apnsCert = 'PushProductionCertificatesWithKey.pem';
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert',$apnsCert); 

    //ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $streamContext); 

    if (!$apns) {
        print "Failed to connect $error $errorString\n";
        return;
    } else {
        print "Connection OK";
    }

    $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload; 


    if(fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage))
    {
        echo "Message send Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Message Sending Fail";
    }
    fclose($apns);

    }
}
```

Here 3 IMP things to consider

1) Port 2195 must be enable on server

2) Certificate for particular application

3) Device token needed